# How to use Cytoscape.js in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, cytoscape.js

I'd like to use Cytoscape.js in my Ember project. So I installed the dependency: `npm install --save cytoscape`. Next I created my Ember component. When I write the component js file, I cannot find out, how to import Cytoscape. I tried `import cytoscape from "cytoscape"`, `var cytoscape = require("cytoscape")` however none of these works.

So how to properly "include" cytoscape to my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Cytoscape needs to be installed via bower and mentioned in `ember-cli-build.js` file like this: `app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js');`. Also information about cytoscape needs to be added to `.jshintrc` file:

`"predef": [
    "document",
    "cytoscape",
    "window",
    "-Promise"
  ],`